# Internet Explorer is uninstalled, no other way to get online; What do I do in order to re-download IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, virus, uninstall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [If the only browser in Windows is dead, how to connect to the Internet?](https://superuser.com/questions/50427/if-the-only-browser-in-windows-is-dead-how-to-connect-to-the-internet)

I got a virus on my computer the other day and I managed to remove the virus and all of the trojans and other stuff it left behind, but it uninstalled all of my programs!
When I tried to open any of my programs the computer opens up the "Open With" box and prompts me to choose one, but even if I chose the corresponding program IT DOES NOT OPEN.

For example, when I try opening Internet Explorer, I chose the Internet Explorer program as the "open with" , so it begins opening IE but then it sends me either to the "Owner" folder in "Documents and Settings" or it asks me to run the installation of the program, and if I click YES it opens IE then closes it and asks me to "Open With". It's a vicious circle.

I don't know what to do. I tried opening MSN Explorer but that is also uninstalled.
So I’m stuck...

Comment: Good question, common question on a lot of forums!

Comment: How are you asking this question if you have no other way to get online ?

Comment: See "If the only browser in Windows is dead, how to connect to the Internet?" at http://superuser.com/questions/50427/if-the-only-browser-in-windows-is-dead-how-to-connect-to-the-internet and "Vista without browser" at http://superuser.com/questions/67199/vista-without-browser

Comment: I really think a better idea at this point is an OS reinstall, especially if you had a bunch of trojans and virus' and you've hacked away at the programs on your system, you future troubles are likely to be bigger than just reinstalling a browser.

Comment: @Studer: What's the meaning of asking a question with an obvious answer? People may have access to internet at their jobs, but no possibility to download stuff to their workstations and burn it on a CD.

Answer (score 2):

In Command Prompt type:

```
ftp releases.mozilla.org
```

At the User prompt enter "anonymous".
At the passowrd prompt, just press <kbd>Return</kbd>.
Then:

```
cd pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/3.6/win32/en-US/
bin
get "Firefox Setup 3.6.exe"
bye
```

I would have offered similar instructions for downloading IE8, but I can't find an FTP download link: **download.microsoft.com** isn't running an FTP server.

Answer (score 1):

Save yourself a lot of trouble and reinstall Windows. If you had a bunch of viruses and trojans on your machine, there are likely still some left, which would explain the behavior you are experiencing. Not having a web browser should be the least of your worries at this point. Don't try to salvage a dead system; do a clean installation and be done with it.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to go to you control panel and then, go to Windows Programs.

Then, put your windows XP CD and then add Internet explorer. You will be prompt to incert the CD. It will installs it by itself.

Or, go on another computer and download the browser you want. Take a USB Key and put it on it. Then install it locally.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't Windows come with ftp? I found [these instructions](http://www.ehow.com/how_2284571_firefox-via-ftp-windows-xp.html). You should do ftp releases.mozilla.org instead of the IP address they list though (they're listing ftp.mozilla.org which is for developers).